# Runtime-dynamic compute graph using Elixir Genstage

Tags: erlang, elixir, genstage

I'd like to be able to dynamically change a compute pipeline at runtime, but it seems that GenStage requires the compute graph to be defined at compile time through the `subscribe_to: [...]` mechanism. Is there a way to create dynamic compute graphs? For example in the below, I'd like to switch, at runtime, between the "subtract 7" and "subtract 4" vertices in my pipeline graph.

[image]

Is this possible using GenStage? I will likely have very complex pipelines so I need a solution that scales to changing graphs in complex ways, as opposed to ad-hoc solutions such as in this case, say, parameterising the integer to subtract. I'd like to be able to add or remove entire sub-trees, switch between subtrees, and add nodes into the graph including splicing them into the middle of any subtree including the main tree.

### Please refer to EDIT further down

Here is the initial producer:

```
defmodule GenstageTest.Producer do
  use GenStage

  def start_link(initial \\ 1) do
    GenStage.start_link(__MODULE__, initial, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(counter), do: {:producer, counter}

  def handle_demand(demand, state) do
    events = Enum.to_list(state..(state + demand - 1))
    {:noreply, events, state + demand}
  end
end
```

Here is one of the producer_consumers:

```
defmodule GenstageTest.PcTimesFive do
  use GenStage

  def start_link do
    GenStage.start_link(__MODULE__, :state_doesnt_matter, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(state) do
    {:producer_consumer, state, subscribe_to: [GenstageTest.PcAddOne]}
  end

  def handle_events(events, _from, state) do
    numbers =
      events
      |> Enum.map(&(&1 * 5))
    {:noreply, numbers, state}
  end
end
```

and here is the final consumer:

```
defmodule GenstageTest.Consumer do
  use GenStage

  def start_link do
    GenStage.start_link(__MODULE__, :state_doesnt_matter)
  end

  def init(state) do
    {:consumer, state, subscribe_to: [GenstageTest.PcDivTwo]}
  end

  def handle_events(events, _from, state) do
    for event <- events do
      IO.inspect({self(), event, state})
    end

    # As a consumer we never emit events
    {:noreply, [], state}
  end
end
```

I
It is all modelled off the [Elixir School Genstage tutorial](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/advanced/gen-stage/).

All the modules and the mix.exs can be [found on github](https://github.com/vegabook/genstage_tes).

### EDIT 3 days later after partial answer from @AquarHEAD L.

I have managed to get runtime subscriptions working. Here are some modified producers, producer_consumers, and consumers respectively:

Producer:

```
defmodule GenstageTest.Producer do
  use GenStage

  def start_link(initial \\ 1) do
    GenStage.start_link(__MODULE__, initial, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(counter), do: {:producer, counter}

  def handle_demand(demand, state) do
    events = Enum.to_list(state..(state + demand - 1))
    {:noreply, events, state + demand}
  end

  def handle_info({:doprint}, state) do
    IO.puts "yep"
    {:noreply, [], state}
  end

  def handle_info({:cancel, sublink}, state) do
    GenStage.cancel sublink, []
    {:noreply, [], state}
  end

end
```

Producter_consumer:

```
defmodule GenstageTest.PcAddOne do
  use GenStage

  def start_link do
    GenStage.start_link(__MODULE__, :state_doesnt_matter, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(state) do
    {:producer_consumer, state}
  end

  def handle_events(events, _from, state) do
    numbers =
      events
      |> Enum.map(&(&1 + 1))
    {:noreply, numbers, state}
  end
end
```

Consumer:

```
defmodule GenstageTest.Consumer do
  use GenStage

  def start_link do
    GenStage.start_link(__MODULE__, :state_doesnt_matter)
  end

  def init(state) do
    {:consumer, state}
  end

  def handle_events(events, _from, state) do
    for event <- events do
      IO.inspect event
      #File.write("/home/tbrowne/scratch/output.txt", 
      #  Kernel.inspect(event) <> " ", [:append])
      :timer.sleep(100)
    end

    # As a consumer we never emit events
    {:noreply, [], state}
  end
end
```

Now once these are all available in the lib directory (remember to add    `{:gen_stage, "~> 0.11"}` to your mix.exs deps), or copied and pasted into IEX, then the following will work perfectly:

```
{:ok, p} = GenstageTest.Producer.start_link(0)
{:ok, a1} = GenstageTest.PcAddOne.start_link()
{:ok, c} = GenstageTest.Consumer.start_link()
{:ok, link1} = GenStage.sync_subscribe(a1, to: p, min_demand: 0, max_demand: 1, cancel: :transient)
{:ok, link2} = GenStage.sync_subscribe(c, to: a1, min_demand: 0, max_demand: 1, cancel: :transient)
```

The issue now is though, that I *still* don't know how to cancel the subscription. There is a [cancel function](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/GenStage.html#cancel/3) and there is also a [stop function](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/GenStage.html#stop/3). `GenStage.stop(c)` for example seems to do nothing, while my various attempts at `GenStage.cancel/3` only give errors.

*To recap, what I need now is to be able to stop certain stages and replace them with others. What is the syntax for cancelling a subcsription, and from where is it called? It is not well explained in the docs as there is no concrete example.*

Comment: It seems they did a dynamic switch on pr `consumer` using a `dynamicSupervisor` in this example: https://medium.com/@andreichernykh/elixir-a-few-things-about-genstage-id-wish-to-knew-some-time-ago-b826ca7d48ba . Maybe you can get an inspiration to do the same on your issue on the producer consumer ? I will try as soon as I have time to, but that will not be today.

Comment: The question is on what circumstances you want to switch one stage? It depends on the data in the pipeline or it is handled externally?

Comment: @Hauleth the idea is that the user will be able to dynamically "what if" with different pipelines, so, pipeline changes will be exogenous events ie: external. Indeed they may well come from an interface similar to that of lunalang https://www.luna-lang.org/

Answer (score 5):

You can absolutely change the pipeline at runtime, [checkout the first example in GenStage documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/GenStage.html#module-example), [you can also use the `:manual` mode to fine control the demand](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/GenStage.html#module-asynchronous-work-and-handle_subscribe). There's also [API to cancel subscription](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/GenStage.html#cancel/3). I think these are enough to dynamically manage GenStage pipelines.

Comment: I have gotten this working well. It's a pity the Elixir School stuff on Genstate doesn't mention this pattern. I have one question though, how does the cancel work? Is it something that must happen within the producer/producer_consumer? IE must it be defined and called from within the producter_consumer? Or can GenStage.cancel be called from externally? I'm getting errors on all permutations. Can you give an example of how to use the cancel? All the rest of the stuff I have been able to use successfully.

Comment: I can't get cancel to work. Do you know how it works?

Comment: @ThomasBrowne sorry was busy at other stuff. Elixir is not OO, so there's no "defined and called from within ..." if I get where you're going with that correctly...

Comment: @ThomasBrowne (accidentally sent the comment before I finish...) you can see from the documentation that GenStage.cancel accepts a "from" type as first argument, click on that it's composed of a pid and a tag, the latter can be obtained from GenStage.sync_subscribe. The pid should be the producer's, by the look of it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I got this working. However I hand to tinker with the buffer lengths to make them stop immediately. I have another question, though. When I use `cancel` it stops the subscription, but also closes the consumer associated with it. Why does it do that? Why doesn't it just stop the _subscription_, and then let me resubscribe to something else from the same running consumer.

Comment: Figured out how to do it: ```GenStage.cancel({p, link1}, :shutdown)```. Note this will only work if you passed ```cancel: :transient``` as in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Why not implement your own `GenStage.Dispatcher`? Here is [behaviour](https://github.com/elixir-lang/gen_stage/blob/master/lib/gen_stage/dispatchers/partition_dispatcher.ex)